# Append DOM elements to the Datatables wrapper

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to add rows to [Datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html) `tbody` using jQuery `append()` Method.

Here's the entire **JavaScript** code:

```
$('#meterGroup').DataTable();
$("#meterListGroup").html("<table id='meterGroup' class='table table-striped table-bordered' cellspacing='0' width='100%'><tbody></tbody></table>");
$("#meterGroup").append("<thead><tr><th>Meter ID</th><th>Energy Consumption (kW)</th><th>Usage Ratio (%)</th></tr></thead>");

var meterId = 1;
var meterConsumption = 155;
var meterRatio = 20;

for (var i = 1; i <= 40; i++) {
  $("#meterListGroup > table > tbody").append("<tr><td>" + meterId + "</td><td>" + meterConsumption + "</td><td>" + meterRatio + "</td></tr>");
  meterId++;
  meterConsumption++;
  meterRatio++;
}
```

and simple **HTML**:

```
<div id="meterListGroup"></div>
```

However, the results of the Datatables is not what I expected. Some element plugins was missing (e.g **Search box**, **Pagination control**, and so on.)

[image]

Where is the mistake? Is there a JSFiddle available for help?

```js
$('#meterGroup').DataTable();
$("#meterListGroup").html("<table id='meterGroup' class='table table-striped table-bordered' cellspacing='0' width='100%'><tbody></tbody></table>");
$("#meterGroup").append("<thead><tr><th>Meter ID</th><th>Energy Consumption (kW)</th><th>Usage Ratio (%)</th></tr></thead>");

var meterId = 1;
var meterConsumption = 155;
var meterRatio = 20;

for (var i = 1; i <= 40; i++) {
  $("#meterListGroup > table > tbody").append("<tr><td>" + meterId + "</td><td>" + meterConsumption + "</td><td>" + meterRatio + "</td></tr>");
  meterId++;
  meterConsumption++;
  meterRatio++;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<h3><i class="fa fa-tachometer" aria-hidden="true"></i> Meter List Information</h3>
<!-- Meter List Information -->
<div id="meterListGroup"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the table **after** you constructed it with `html()` and `append()`.

```js
$("#meterListGroup").html("<table id='meterGroup' class='table table-striped table-bordered' cellspacing='0' width='100%'><tbody></tbody></table>");

// ... skipped ...

$('#meterGroup').DataTable();
```

See [updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/67vL2gwm/1/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Thanks! That helps.